# Determine all solutions of the equation in $\mathbb{R}, (x^2 + 3x – 4)^3 + (2x^2– 5x + 3)^3 = (3x^2 – 2x – 1)^3$

Tags: contest-math, problem-solving

What are the steps you follow while solving for variables in an equation?

From easy to difficult or tricky or exhausting, how do you solve for variables in an equation. Is there any algorithm or strategy to solve it. I am new to such level of maths, so asking as a intermediate. You may forward a link that helped you. Thanks in advance.

Here is a question (of such difficulty), you may solve, so that the post doesn't seems too subjective.

Determine all solutions of the equation in Real number, $(x^2 + 3x – 4)^3 + (2x^2 – 5x + 3)^3 = (3x^2 – 2x – 1)^3$

Comment: Kindly show your work, whatever it may be.

Comment: This is 6th order polynomial equation. In general, these cannot be solved exactly. In this case however, the terms in brackets add up in a simple way, and we have an equation of the form $a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3$. This should simplify to something you can work with.

Comment: Observe that if $A,B$ and $C$ are the polynomials inside the cubes, then $C=A+B$. Therefore, your equation is $A^3+B^3=(A+B)^3=A^3+B^3+3AB(A+B)$, which is equivalent to $0=AB(A+B)=(x^2+3x-4)(2x^2-5x+3)(3x^2-2x-1)=(x+4)(x-1)(x-1)(2x-3)(3x+1)(x-1)$.

Comment: Based on other questions you've asked, it looks like what you are really looking for are tips on how to approach contest-type math problems. If indeed that's the case, it would help if you edited your question(s) to include that as context. As is, a suitable hint for your question here to simply expand the trinomials on each side, simplify things down to a polynomial of degree $6$, and then see if you can factor it. For contest-type problems, a suitable hint is to see if there is some unexpectedly simple relationship among the expressions constituting the problem... (cont.)

Comment: ...(cont.)  in this case, as @Blitzer points out, the two quadratics on the left hand side sum to the quadratic on the right. Surely that must help!

Answer (score 3):

Consider $\;x^2+3x-4=a\;,\;2x^2-5x+3=b\;$ and observe that the given equation is $\;a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3\;.$

$$a^3+b^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)$$
$$\implies ab(a+b)=0$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, I can. It implies that
$x^2+3x-4=0\;\;$ or $\;\;2x^2-5x+3=0\;\;$ or $\;\;3x^2-2x-1=0\;.$
So the solutions are :
$S=\left\{-4,1\text{ (thrice) },\dfrac32,-\dfrac13\right\}\;.$

Comment: @Angelo You answer as if you were the OP ... :)

Comment: I only wanted to know if my answer is correct. Can you tell me it?

Comment: @Angelo absolutely correct